# How to access Office Outlook API from Google App engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, outlook, office365

I need to access data of Outlook calendar/contacts hosted online on [outlook.com](http://outlook.com). Account was set up for free. I am not sure if it can be accessed via Office 356 API. What is the general approach to get / put data to Outlook calendar/contacts using application hosted on Google AppEngine?

Comment: Have you tried anything and experiencing any issues? If so - provide more details what's not working. If not - working with their API shouldn't be any different form any other API providers, read their docs, start working on it and ask more specific questions if you run into any difficulties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a difference between Outlook and Outlook.com (confusing as it may be).

Briefly, the former refers to the popular email solution used by enterprises. The latter refers to what used to be known as hotmail.com

Both are currently completely different and thus have different APIs. It seems like you want to access the contacts and calendar data of outlook.com users. If so, you can check out the Outlook.com API here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh826535.aspx

For example, if you want to create/read contacts of Outlook.com users, this section is relevant: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh826527.aspx

And this section shows you how to interact with calendars on Outlook.com: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh826523.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your question!  Currently, Office 365 API work for Office 365 users and not outlook.com users.  Support for outlook.com is on our roadmap, but I don't have a timeline to share yet.  Please let me know if you have any questions or need more info.

Thanks,

Venkat